# How to config OpenTok change status of Archive from "UPLOADED" to "AVAILABLE"?

Tags: archive, opentok

Steps for Reproduct:
1. I config OpenTok storage video on Amazon S3.
2. I call api startArchive to start streaming video.
3. I call api StopArchive to stop streaming video.
4. I check status of this archive on OpenTok. It's has status "UPLOADED".
5. I login to Amazon S3. The video file that I streaming above is exist on Amazon S3.
6. The status of archive on OpenTok is still "UPLOADED". It's not change to "AVAILABLE". The url value of archive is null.

I don't know the reason that status of archive not change to "AVAILABLE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokbox developer here

Please note that "AVAILABLE" is only used when you don't provide a custom s3 bucket to upload the archive, and the file is uploaded to tokbox cloud [1]

So:

- if you you specify your bucket, the status will be: STARTED->STOPPED->UPLOADED
- if you don't specify your bucket, the status will be: STARTED->STOPPED->AVAILABLE

[1] https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/#status

Comment: Hi Jose Carlos, Can we get url of video file If we use Amazon S3 to storage?
I setup Amazon S3 to upload the archive but the archive url is always null.